# syntax of operator new in c++ new to me

Tags: c++, templates, new-operator

i am new with c++ and i have a piece of code below that i am unable to understand

```
from_net_fifos = new my_fifo_t <net_cmd_t> ** [NUM_PRIORITIES];
```

To be specific, I dont get what the ** means here.

I got this much from the code.

`my_fifo_t` is a template, `net_cmd_t` is a type which is a struct ,

the number of fifos created = number of priorities, ie each message with a different prirority has its own fifo queue. So basically we are creating fifo of type net_cmd_t, ie each element is of this struct type in the fifo. The number of fifos created equals the variable `NUM_PRIORITIES`.

What does ** do here?
Can someone correct me if i am wrong and explain the exact syntax of this line of code?

Comment: The real question is why you have a `my_fifo_t<net_cmd_t> ***`.

Comment: @Chris Whoever wrote that was a [three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer), clearly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The asterisks `*` are used to denote pointers, and the statement allocates `NUM_PRIORITES` pointers to pointers to `my_fifo_t`. You can think of it as an array of arrays of pointers to `my_fifo_t`.

Comment: so new here is allocating memory to an array of pointers which point to fifos but not the fifo itself? Does this line allocate memory to the fifo also?

Comment: @user2179788 The statement only allocates memory for the first level of the array. Then it needs to be allocated like `from_net_fifos[i] = new my_fifo_t * [SOME_SIZE];`, and that array needs to be initialized as well: `from_net_fifos[i][j] = new my_fifo_t;`.

Comment: Perfect! this follows it in the code , now i get it.. thanks a lot :)                                                                 for (int p = 0; p < NUM_PRIORITIES; ++p) {
    from_net_fifos[p] = new my_fifo_t <net_cmd_t> * [num_ports];

Comment: @JoachimPileborg of course, it's always possible the last dimension is an array too :) (`from_net_fifos[i][j] = new my_fifo_t[SIZE]`)

Comment: the last dimension in my case is a single structure i think , this is how it is defined,  for (int i = 0; i < num_ports; ++i) {
 from_net_fifos[p][i] = new my_fifo_t <net_cmd_t>;